# flutter channel master command not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have a project which requires the dart sdk version to be more than 2.19.0. And to do this I am trying to run the commands `flutter channel master` and then `flutter upgrade`. Now when I run flutter channel master, I get this error

```
git: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
git:    packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dropdown.dart
git:    packages/flutter/lib/src/material/expand_icon.dart
git: Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
git: Aborting
Switching channels failed with error code 1.
```

Now I am not sure where exactly are these files present. And how can I upgrade the dart sdk.

I am expecting to upgrade the dart sdk version.